# C++ - design question

Tags: c++, templates, virtual

I am working on game engine prototype and have the following question:

Right now my engine implementation is DirectX-bound and everything works fine.

I've got a `core::Renderer` class which has methods to *render geometry, set shaders, lightning, etc...*

*Some of them are templated, some not.*

```
class Renderer {

   // ...
   template <typename Geometry> RenderGeometry(shared_ptr<Geometry> geometry);
};
```

---

Let's say I want to extend the flexibility of my engine and I wan't it to work using DirectX and OpenGL. As I understand it right now, the idea is to take everything interface-specific to the base `core::Renderer` class, make all those calls `virtual` and then provide their *DirectX-specific* and *OpenGL-specific* implementation.

If my geometrical object wasn't a template, everything would look better:

```
class Renderer {

   virtual void RenderGeometry(shared_ptr<core::Non_template_Geometry> geometry);

};

class DXRenderer {

   // Here goes our custom implementation
   // for DirectX-based geometry rendering
   virtual void RenderGeometry(...)
};

// The same for OpenGL
```

***The problem with the first (initial variant) is that virtual functions are not allowed to be templated.***

***So here comes the question - how should I solve it?***

Any hacks / tricks / patterns for this situation or for *template virtual functions* emulation?

Comment: "Let's say I want to extend the flexibility" Advice: adding flexibility is a bad idea - will eat your development time. Don't do that unless you have to. Same goes about additional API support. Unless you can't live without support for additional 3D api, don't add it.

Comment: @SigTerm Well, at least I would like to know how to solve this kind of problem. And, because it's a hobby project, I do have a lot of time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a base `Geometry` class:

```
class Geometry {
public:
    virtual ~Geometry() { }
    virtual void Render() = 0;
};
```

and have each of your Geometry-type classes derive from this base class and implement their specific rendering functionality by overriding `Render`.

Then, `Renderer::RenderGeometry` does not need to be a function template; it can simply take a pointer to the base `Geometry` class and call the virtual function `Render`.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are some troubles. Geometry should be independent from vertex type, which in my case is another template. I could probably solve this operating on some `variant`-type, but I thought there is a better workaround. *Anyway, thanks.*

Comment: @HardCoder1986:  You can derive any number of types from the base `Geometry` class, so you could have a concrete class template derived from `Geometry` that also takes as a template argument the vertex type.

Answer (score 1):

Template is not neccessity. If you think hard about it, most of the time templates only do text-replacing and is a safer macros.

OOP was not design to rely heavily on templates, but composition and inheritance (like what James suggested)